# How can I pass data from a database to an ng multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angular

This is the ts component

```
export class OnlineApplicationsComponent implements OnInit { public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/batches'; data: ITransactionDetail[];
```

the variable data refers to an interface in the application and it stores a collection of json data

In the ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.dropdownList = this.data; this.dropdownSettings = { singleSelection: false, idField: 'itemId', textField: 'itemText', 
};
```

These are the codes in the html file

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select'" [settings]="dropdownSettings" [data]="data" >
```

Comment: The code is not readable. Also can you share the data?

Comment: When {{ data | json }} is on the html component, it reveals this [ { "id": 29105, "createDate": null, "createdBy": "Administrator Administrator", "status": null, "transactionNumber": null, "transactionType": "Governor's Consent", "party": null }, } ] on the webpage.

Comment: Okay so you need to change the dropdown setting. `idField: 'id'` and `textField: 'createdBy'`. That's what I could understand from your JSON.

Comment: You're welcome and please accept the added answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to wrong id and text field in your `dropdownSetting`. I have modified the setting based upon your `JSON` response.

```
this.dropdownSettings = { 
    singleSelection: false,
    idField: 'id',
    textField: 'createdBy', 
};
```